# Facebook4j - get access and post to different groups

Tags: java, facebook, facebook4j

I have a question regarding facebook4j API for Java.
I would like to have the following:
- I have a webapp with different user
- Each user can post with his Facebook Account to different groups
- This means I have to store from every user the different API Keys
- The Key should not expire, is this possible?

Here a sample code for get access:

```
public class LoginFacebook {

public static String appId = "myAppId";   // Sample values
public static String appSecret = "myAppSecret";
public static String access_token = "myToken";

public static Facebook facebook;

public RecuperationFacebook() {
    facebook = new FacebookFactory().getInstance();
    facebook.setOAuthAppId(appId, appSecret);
    facebook.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(access_token));
}

public static Comment Commentaire(String id_comment) throws FacebookException {
    Comment commentaire =facebook.getComment(id_comment, null);
    return(commentaire);
}
```

}

Question:
- How get every user his API Key?
- What are the different API Keys? (appId, appSecret, access_token) ?

Many thanks for help

Comment: No it is not possible. User accesstokens do expire

Comment: hm and what´s that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FtboHvg3HtY

Comment: That is how you get a page access token.

Comment: What is a page access token?

Comment: It is an access token to interact with pages you own. Not groups.

Comment: When will the API Key expire for user? If  the user will renew the credentials every 60 days, than it´s also OK... I mean "Tinder" etc. is using also my credentials to login etc.?

Comment: It will expire after 60 days if you have a long term access token. And within hours if you have a short term one. To extend it you pop the login dialog.